# Spit and Slurp a vector in Clojure

Tags: serialization, clojure

I am trying to spit a vector like [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]] into a file and later slurp it, but when I slurp it I get a string not a vector. Even if I evaluate the string I get, it is still gives a string. I tried to use (vectors slurpt-string) still it give a one element vector containing the string. 
Any comments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[clojure.core/read-string](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/read-string)**

`(spit "foo" [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]])`

`(slurp "foo") ; "[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]"`

`(read-string *1) ; [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]`

`(type *1) ; clojure.lang.PersistentVector`

---

`(read-string "[[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]")`

Comment: @Ali Be careful what you read with read-string though. It can reads any object that can be read, not just a vector. That includes code. If *read-eval* is set to true (and it is by default) and the string uses the #= read-eval macro, read-string can even execute code. Therefore, it's possible for it to be used maliciously. For example, somebody replaces the vector in your file with code to `rm -rt /home/ali/` ;)

Comment: @Rayne I actually want to use this to send updated versions of a vector from a server to clients and back. My environment is a local cluster not connected to outside and I consider it to be free of malicious activity! (I know, I know!). But If it was not, then I need to get the string and parse it to make sure I am evaluating only the vector right?

Comment: @Ali You could just set `*read-eval*` to false using binding before you `read-string` the vector: `(binding [*read-eval* false] (read-string ..))`. Then, you can just check and make sure it's a vector and go on about your business.

Comment: For those reading in the modern era of Clojure, just use `(clojure.edn/read-string (slurp "file or url"))` to avoid running possibly malicious code. You may have to `(require 'clojure.edn)` first.